# Decoding JSON PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode a JSON using, But I am unable to read the node results.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$request =  'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDMXN%22%2C%20%22USDCHF%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=';
$session = curl_init($request);  
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$json = curl_exec($session);     
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
if(!is_null($obj->query->results)){
  // Safe to parse datae
  echo results .'</br>';
}

print_r( $obj['results']);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON

```
 {
 "query": {
  "count": 2,
  "created": "2014-01-26T01:20:15Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "user-time": "259",
   "service-time": "341",
   "build-version": "0.2.2157"
  },
  **"results": {**
   "rate": [
    {
     "id": "USDMXN",
     "Name": "USD to MXN",
     "Rate": "13.4525",
     "Date": "1/25/2014",
     "Time": "7:20am",
     "Ask": "13.453",
     "Bid": "13.452"
    },
    {
     "id": "USDCHF",
     "Name": "USD to CHF",
     "Rate": "0.8945",
     "Date": "1/25/2014",
     "Time": "7:20am",
     "Ask": "0.8947",
     "Bid": "0.8943"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

I am trying to get the node "results", so that I can get the currency rates that can be used to display in websites.

This code uses yahoo api to get the currency conversion rates.

Comment: What is this `**"results": {**`

Comment: `json_decode($json, true);` returns an array. If you want an object, omit the second argument (or set it to false).

Comment: A simple print_r($obj) would give you a pretty good idea of what you're doing wrong.

Comment: <?php   $request =  'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDMXN%22%2C%20%22USDCHF%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=';
    $session = curl_init($request);  
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $json = curl_exec($session);     
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    print_r($obj['query']['results']);
    ?>
http://i.stack.imgur.com/kN6tt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using true as parameter  in `json_decode` you will get an array.

Try

```
 if(!is_null($obj['results']['rate'])){
     foreach($obj['results']['rate'] as $value){
      echo "{$value['Name']} => {$value['Rate']}<br>";
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You've got to use `$obj->results` because it s at the same level than query.

Comment: this won't work, he is getting an array, not an object since he is passing `true` as parameter of `json_decode()` function and should be `$obj['results']['rate']`